# Django evaluate string vs array

Tags: django

I am sometimes getting passed a string and sometimes getting an array and trying to figure go about displaying them. For example

```
if string { handle string }
if array { handle array }
```

what I have come up with is the following which almost works. The problem is slicing a string just returns a character and slicing an array returns a string so I cant make any kind of comparison. Is there a way to check if something is a string vs an array? I didn't see this capability anywhere in the documentation. Is it just this primitive?

```
{% if person|lookup:'items'|slice:":1"|length > 1 %} {{ person|lookup:'items' }}{% else %} {{ i }} {% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, it (the template language) is intentionally this primitive. You should implement all your business logic in the views and leave only the presentation to your templates. Alternatively you can write a custom filter that does it at the template level.

Comment: Following on from @Selcuk, the usual way to do this would be to use Python tools such as `isinstance` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) in the view, then just pass the relevant data to the template.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks, I do not have the ability to use Python tools since its part of a platform I do not have access to. What I wound up doing is adding a space at the beginning of the string so I can evaluate it. It is not a solution but is a hack workaround for now.